# Render non-ascii chars correctly in Info buffers?

Tags: unicode, info

I'm reading the Emacs manual in Info-mode. Some non-ascii characters render as octal escape sequences rather than glyphs. For example, node 23.2 [Minor Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html#Minor-Modes) contains the following text:

> Electric Quote mode automatically converts quotation marks.  For
>   example, it requotes text typed `like this' to text ‘like
>   this’.

When I view it in an info buffer, I see:

> Electric Quote mode automatically converts quotation marks.  For
>   example, it requotes text typed `like this' to text \342\200\230like
>   this\342\200\231.

If I select this text and write the region to a file, I can open that file and Emacs renders it correctly.

I'm running Emacs in a gui, but I've repro'd everything above in the terminal as well, and both with and without my init file.

What's causing this behavior, and how can I fix it so info buffers render correctly?

Comment: If you see this when starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) then please consider reporting it as an Emacs bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If you do not see it with virgin Emacs the recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit code.

Comment: What emacs version are you on?

Comment: Are you on OSX, and is your `texinfo` program 4.8? This sounds like [bug#24637](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24637). The fix is to upgrade to 4.13 or higher.

Comment: @npostavs That is the right bug. I reported it :) . I would upgrade but it sounds like I'd have to force link it, and given how low impact it is, I'm more inclined to let it lay for now.

Comment: Oh, that's why it seemed so familiar :) I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Bug#24637](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24637), as explained there, the problem is due to a bug in old versions of Texinfo.  It should be solved by upgrading to version 4.13 or higher.

> I would upgrade but it sounds like I'd have to force link it

I don't exactly know what "force link" means, but you should be able to do `./configure MAKEINFO=/path/to/new/makeinfo` when building emacs without having to override makeinfo in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config file:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Also, if you run emacs in tmux, add this to tmux config:

```
set -gq utf8
setw -gq utf8 on
```

Comment: Still no luck. Though this changed the default coding system for new files from utf-8-unix to utf-8, running `describe-coding` in the Info buffer reports `Coding system for saving this buffer: t -- raw-text-unix` both before and after adding the above settings.

Comment: Which font do you use? Does it support UTF-8?

Comment: I use Avenir Next in Info buffers, and it supports utf-8, but I also repro'd this issue without any of my personal config, in which case Emacs is using Menlo. Menlo also supports utf-8